# ¿Como puedo adjuntar un archivo PDF a un registro de una BD en SQL con C#?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, pdf

Existe alguna posibilidad de adjuntar archivos PDF o cualquier tipo de archivo a un registro de una BD en SQL Server 2008 R2 desde una aplicación de C# hecha con VS 2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En realidad no importa la versión del IDE que uses, con C# puedes hacer muchas cosas, y entre ellas puedes optar por serializar el archivo (PDF o cualquier otro) a una cadena Base64 y guardarla como si fuera un string:

---

```
using System;
using System.IO;

public class Serializador
{
    public static bool GuardarArchivo(string archivo)
    {
        // Leemos todos los bytes del archivo y luego lo guardamos como Base64 en un string.
        string resultado = Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(archivo));

        using (var cn = 
            new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString))
        {
            using(var cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
            {
                // Se invoca a un StoreProcedure para insertar el registro.
                cmd.CommandText = "usp_InsertArchivo";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoreProcedure;
                // Con la ayuda de FileInfo devolvemos unicamente el nombre del archivo.
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nombreArchivo", new FileInfo(archivo).Name);
                // El resultado serializado del archivo pasa como un varchar cualquiera.
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contenido", resultado);

                cn.Open();

                int cantidad = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Si es mayor a 0 entonces se guardo correctamente.
                return (cantidad > 0);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Que ventaja se lograria al grabar el archivo como base64 por sobre persistir directo el binario? si se define un campo varbinary seria directo sin ninguna conversion de tipos, el byte[] como parametro

Comment: La ventaja sería que es multiplataforma, por ejemplo si quisieras reconstruir el archivo en un dispositivo móvil a través de un servicio WCF

Comment: Pero si es algo movile podria convertir a base64 al momento de enviar el archivo, y sino es movile se envia directo el byte[]. Ademas WCF puede enviar un binario directamente como parte del DataContract, el servicio le aplica el encode directamente. Mas que nada la duda la tengo porque base64 ocupa mas espacio de almacenamiento.

Answer (score 2):

Sí, es posible. Tienes tres alternativas:

1. Almacenar el archivo directamente en base de datos como tipo [`Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb895234.aspx) y almacenar el binario directamente.
2. Almacenar el archivo directamente en base de datos con tipo [`FileStream`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).
3. Almacenar el archivo en disco y guardar la ruta del archivo en un campo de tu tabla en la base de datos.

Cada alternativa tiene sus pros y contras luego de varias discusiones al respecto. La más recomendada  que he visto para SQL Server (al menos sobre imágenes, pero aplica a cualquier tipo de archivo) es **la segunda**. En caso que no uses SQL Server, la segunda opción queda descartada y te recomendaría la tercera porque facilita el mantenimiento de los archivos, la base de datos no es tan pesada, existe separación de asuntos, facilita las pruebas, etc.

Acá más información al respecto: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3748/1065197

Answer (score 2):

Si es posible, aunque no es recomendable

Puedes declarar tu columna como `VARBINARY` en Sql

Y el código para subir el archivo seria mas o meno sería algo así:

```
byte[] byteArray = cargarArchivo(); //Regresa tu archivo como un arreglo de bytes
var command = new SqlCommand("Insert Into Tu_Tabla columna_archivo Values (@archivo)" , sqlConection); // Creamos un SqlCommand que tenga un insert comun, pero apuntando a la columna
command.Parameters.Add("@archivo", SqlDbType.VarBinary, byteArray.Length).Value = byteArray; //Pasamos la referencia del arreglo de bytes
command.ExecuteNonQuery();// Y ejecutamos el query sin retorno
```

Trabajar con archivos dentro de la base de datos no es una práctica muy buena, ya que las inserciones y peticiones son más costosas que simple texto o algún otro tipo numérico. Pero si es posible.

[Aquí](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/150787) se toca ese tema en inglés, dale una mirada ;)

Answer (score 1):

Aquí

[[ASP.NET] Grabar Archivo en base de datos](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/aspnet-grabar-archivo-en-base-de-datos.html)

explico como podrias insertar un archivo dentro de un campo en la tabla

Como veras se define en la tabla un campo del tipo `varbinary` y para insertar debes pasar por parametro al `INSERT` un array de bytes.

Si tu aplicación es `winforms` es muy simple solo usas el [File.ReadAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx)()

En el ejemplo del link el código que resulta util esta en la capa de persistencia

```
    public static void Guardar(string nombrearchivo, int length, byte[] archivo)
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = @"INSERT INTO Archivos (nombre, length, archivo)
                             VALUES (@name, @length, @archivo)";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nombrearchivo);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@length", length);

            SqlParameter archParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@archivo", SqlDbType.VarBinary);
            archParam.Value = archivo;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        }

    }
```

generando un parametro en el INSERT que permita asignar el byte[] del archivo

---

Ademas recomendaría validades sino te resulta util definir el campo como `FileStream`, por la version de `Sql Server` que mencionas puedes usarlo y es mas óptimo a la hora de registrar archivos en la db.

[An Introduction to SQL Server FileStream](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/)

[How Do I: Use SQL File Stream](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream)