# ¿Como puedo descargar un archivo PDF de un registro en un BD de MySQL con C#?

Tags: c#, mysql

Con ayuda de esta consulta,(
[¿Como puedo adjuntar un archivo PDF a un registro de una BD en SQL con C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/3947/como-puedo-adjuntar-un-archivo-pdf-a-un-registro-de-una-bd-en-sql-con-c) ) y 
 con algunas pequeñas modificaciones pude agregar un archivo PDF a una tabla MySQL, ahora tengo tengo el problema inverso, esto es necesito poder descargar el archivo cargado, estoy utilizando VS2015, de ante mano gracias....

Comment: Que es un "BD"?

Comment: es una Base de Datos

Comment: Vaya! En Ingles "DB", y asi me fue confundido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la anterior pregunta en el articulo que sugiero explico como descargar un archivo

[[ASP.NET] Grabar Archivo en base de datos](http://ltuttini.blogspot.com.ar/2011/03/aspnet-grabar-archivo-en-base-de-datos.html)

Si analizas la capa de datos veras el metodo para recuperar un archivo por el id.

```
    public static byte[] GetById(int Id)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"].ToString()))
        {
            conn.Open();

            string query = @"SELECT archivo
                            FROM Archivos
                            WHERE Id = @id";

            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Id);

            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                return (byte[])reader["archivo"];
            }

        }

        return null;

    }
```

lo importante es ver como se asigna el contenido del campo como `byte[]` en la linea del return

Con ese resultado deberias enviarlo en el `Response` al cliente para su descarga. Haya varias formas de lograr la descarga pero la mas simple es por medio de una pagina que podrias llamarse `download.aspx`

```
public partial class Download : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);

        byte[] archivo = ArchivosDAL.GetById(id);

        Response.Clear();

        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "nombrearch.pdf"));
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

        Response.BinaryWrite(archivo.ContenidoArchivo);
        Response.End();

    }
}
```

Se define el `ContentType = "application/octet-stream"` para que muestre el cuadro de descarga en lugar de mostrar el pdf embebido en el browser

Comment: muchas gracias a ambos por la ayuda, descarga el archivo a la perfección, pero tengo ahora otra duda ¿? ¿como puedo abrir el archivo en un formulario de ASP?, la idea sería sin necesidad de descargar  el archivo al equipo del cliente, ¿se entiende?

Comment: en ese caso cambia el ContentType definiendo application/pdf de esta forma el browser lo reconocera y lo abrira embebido

Comment: ok, realice algunas modificaciones  y al final quedó de la siguiente manera...<br/>
        `Response.Clear();  <br/>

        //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition",String.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "nombrearch.pdf"));  
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";  

        Response.BinaryWrite(archivo.ContenidoArchivo);  
        Response.End();  .`

Comment: Que paso que desmarcaste la respuesta? un archivo no se guarda NUNCA como base64 si puede persistirlo en un campo varbinary. Si lo persistes como string es una pesima idea. Lo unico que lo podria justificar usar base64 es si defines junto a la imagen metadatos en un xml

Answer (score 0):

El codigo de la liga que expones, guarda en la DB el PDF en Base64, ahora debes realizar lo contrario decodificar el Base64 a archivo fisico, y eso lo haces de la siguiente manera.

Suponiendo ya tengas en una variable el base64 del PDF obtenido mediante una consulta o algo similar, ejemplo b64Str

Lo conviertes a archivo de la siguiente manera

```
Byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(b64Str);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```